# Oracle sql count of join gives me error of 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here is my query which tries to get  how many CUSTOMER_IDs listed in the CUSTOMERS table are already in the TRANSACTIONS table too.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID
        FROM
            CUSTOMERS
        INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONS 
        ON CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID = TRANSACTIONS.CUSTOMER_ID
    )
```

This query returns

> 904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier error.

How can i fix my query?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM`?!? What's that expected to return?

Comment: `DISTINCT COUNT(*)` is probably not what you meant, have a look at this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=66e75715e5e9949ac62cbae2b9599684 for an idea of what it does. As for your actual error, which line and column does the error message refer to?

Comment: I tried to get count of every different CUSTOMER_IDs of join query. What is the true method can you help me please?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewSayer I think I get the idea of COUNT() but the problem is it still gives me identifier error and I can't get the count of customers which intersects between CUSTOMERS and TRANSACTIONS tables

Comment: @merts97 Please get the full error message, you should get a line number and a column number to indicate which word in your query is invalid. Then make sure that is really correct - eg if it's `CUSTOMER_ID` make sure that's what the column is called. If your error message is just what you've shared then I suggest running the query from something like Sql*plus or SQL Developer which won't hide this detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `count(*)` will always return a single number, so doing a `distinct` on it is unnecessary. It sounds like you want something more like:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID )
  FROM CUSTOMERS
 INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONS 
         ON CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID = TRANSACTIONS.CUSTOMER_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `customer_id` in `transactions` can only be a valid `customers.customer_id`, then you can very much simplify this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T.CUSTOMER_ID)
FROM TRANSACTIONS T;
```

This is a very reasonable assumption.  In a properly structured database, `TRANSACTIONS.CUSTOMER_ID` would be declared as a foreign key to `CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID`.